# Not able to get the value

Tags: c#, class, methods

First, this is my first question, sorry for not following the guidelines, my bad, and will do a better job next time.

In short, I have the lotto draw values in a CSV file which I am able to read and they go into an array.  Once in the array, I do have to apply some statistical formula to each row (balls) so I basically create another array to hold those values. But it seems that I am not declaring it high enough.

I got a few comments so far but not really where it bugs me. It has to do on how do I make "tirages" global so I can access its content throughout my code?

if you look in the code, around 40th row you'll see this
...

```
int derniertirageacompter = tirages.Count;
Console.WriteLine($"dernier tirage: {derniertirageacompter}")
```

...
which return 0. But I reference to tirages elsewhere in "Load_649_CSV" and it works fine. I tried the solution visual studio proposed but didn't work so here I am.

I believe the issue is with "tirages" and how/where it is declared but I have no clue. Obviously, I am not a programmer! I wrote a program in Excel VBA 20 years ago and I am trying to rewrite it in c#. I will have to use tons of arrays to recreate the spreadsheets I did use that store formulas and data.  This is the reason why I am trying to access tirages globally.

...

```
//Main Program
//
namespace Lotto_649
{
    class Program
    {
        //public static object Frequence { get; private set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Nb_Boule;//49 for 649 and 50 for Lotto_MAX
            
            MenuPrincipale();//display the main menu

            //load the draw based on the choice
            int Menu_Lotto_Choice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (Menu_Lotto_Choice)//faire une selection
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Loading 649");
                    Load_649_CSV();//call method for loading the 649 drwas
                    Nb_Boule = 49;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("To Do Lotto MAX");
                    //Load_Lotto_max();//call method for the lotto max draw 
                    Nb_Boule = 50;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Error - Break");//any other keys
                    break;
            }//end switch

            //this is where I have I think an issue!
            var tirages = new List<Tirage>();

            int derniertirageacompter = tirages.Count;
            Console.WriteLine($"dernier tirage: {derniertirageacompter}");
        }

        //---------------------------Declaring the method used in the main program

        //Load the 649 draw in the array. 
        public static void Load_649_CSV()
        {
            //read the content of the CSV file as plain text
            //read all the lines and put it directly into an array
            //Date,Boule 1,Boule 2,Boule 3,Boule 4,Boule 5,Boule 6,Complementaire,Valeur,Even - Odd,Buckets

            string[] csvAllTirage649 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\repos\CSV-Reader-with-lotto\Tirage649.csv");
            int Num_of_Draw_to_Check;//variable that determine how many draw to check
               
            //**Declaring the array tirages**
            //How to declare the array so its available globally? is this the way to do it?
             var tirages = new List<Tirage>();

            Console.WriteLine($"There are {csvAllTirage649.Length} in the file.");
            Console.WriteLine($"How many resutls to load?");
            string v = Console.ReadLine();
            //**add error catcher

            Num_of_Draw_to_Check = Convert.ToInt16(v);

            for (int i = 1; i < Num_of_Draw_to_Check; i++)//start with 1 since 0 content the header
            {
                Tirage draw = new Tirage(csvAllTirage649[i]);//creat the array drawy abd laod the results into it.
                tirages.Add(draw);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"The {Num_of_Draw_to_Check} sesutls are loaded");
        }// End Load_649_CSV
       
        //----------------------Print to screen the menu---------------------------------
        private static void MenuPrincipale()
        {
            //menu principale
            Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"Beginning of the program");
            Console.WriteLine($"Select the lotto type");
            Console.WriteLine($"1 - 649");
            Console.WriteLine($"2 - Lotto Max");
            Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
            //end menuprincipale
        }
    }
}
```

...

and this is my class
...

```
namespace Lotto_649
{
    //on defini la classe tirage qui est utiliser pour lire le fichier CSV
    public class Tirage
    {
        public DateTime t_Date;
        public int B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, Comp, Somme_Tir_wo_Compl, Pair;
        //should I use and array to store the boule value?
        //public int[] Boules = new int[6];
        public string Montant, Even_Odd, Bucket;

        public Tirage(string rowTirage649)
        {
            // Date,Boule 1,Boule 2,Boule 3,Boule 4,Boule 5,Boule 6,Complementaire,Valeur,Even - Odd,Buckets
            
            string[] data = rowTirage649.Split(',');
            //parse data into properties
            //convert from a string to a date
            this.t_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(data[0]);
            //convert from a string to int
            this.B1 = Convert.ToInt16(data[1]);
            this.B2 = Convert.ToInt16(data[2]);
            this.B3 = Convert.ToInt16(data[3]);
            this.B4 = Convert.ToInt16(data[4]);
            this.B5 = Convert.ToInt16(data[5]);
            this.B6 = Convert.ToInt16(data[6]);
            this.Comp = Convert.ToInt16(data[7]);
            this.Montant = data[8];
            this.Even_Odd = data[9];
            this.Bucket = data[10];

            this.Somme_Tir_wo_Compl = B1 + B2 + B3 + B4 + B5 + B6;

            //init Pair, then count the nombre de boule pair.
            Pair = 0;
            {
                if (B1 % 2 == 0)
                    Pair++;
                if (B2 % 2 == 0)
                    Pair++;
                if (B3 % 2 == 0)
                    Pair++;
                if (B4 % 2 == 0)
                    Pair++;
                if (B5 % 2 == 0)
                    Pair++;
                if (B6 % 2 == 0)
                    Pair++;
            }

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string str = $"{t_Date} {B1} {B2} {B3} {B4} {B5} {B6} {Comp} {Montant} {Even_Odd} {Pair}:";
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

...

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Highlight a code section using your mouse and then click on `{ }` to mark it as code.

Comment: You [posted too much code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/); probably because you don't know what causes the problem. You [haven't provided debugging details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). All these things suggest you have [done no debugging](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) Yu need to do that before posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You will likely find that your code is more readable if you do something to split up words for the reader.  For example, compare `dernierTirageACompter` to `derniertirageacompter`.  The former is much more readable

Comment: It is not clear what is not working in the code you posted, never mind what the exact problem is, nor what _specifically_ you need help with. Please rewrite your question so that it includes a proper [mcve] -- i.e. a code example with **only** just the code needed to demonstrate the problem, and explain _exactly_ what error message(s) you get, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: In the line above `int derniertirageacompter = tirages.Count;`, you have `var tirages = new List<Tirage>();`. When `Console.WriteLine($"dernier tirage: {derniertirageacompter}");` 
 occurs, you haven't added anything to the list, so why would the count be > 0? Also, I noticed, in Tirage, that you declared B1, B2, etc... as `int`, but then use `Convert.ToInt16`. `int` is Int32. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types for more information.

Comment: Do you have some sample data that is in "Tirage649.csv"?

Comment: please share sample csv data from which the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. This is my first question and I do realize now that I made some newbie mistake in the way I formulated my question and way too much code I pasted.  Nevertheless, I got a couple of great advice on my code but really where I am stuck is with {"tirages"} and how to access it globally throughout my code and now only in Load_649_CSV.  @user9938 Here is also a sample of a row from the CSV file: 2021-03-21, 3, 5, 12, 23, 35, 49, 23, 45M, 3E, 32452.

Comment: @B4SE: It's not quite clear what you mean by "...with {"tirages"} and how to access it globally throughout my code". Your program doesn't seem that complex. Option 1 in my answer below may be what you are looking for. Since most of your code is contained within "Program.cs", by using a class (class-level) variable, that variable becomes available to all methods in "Program.cs".

Comment: It does work fine with your solution, I'm able to continue on with the programming based on the example given.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code below is your code with some modifications. I've added some comments in the code. Further modifications to the code below may be necessary based on your requirements/objective(s).

Since it's mostly your code, there doesn't seem to be a need to provide a lot of explanation.

**Resources**:

- [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions)
- [Control variable scope and logic using code blocks in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/)
- [Basic concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts)
- [Using Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)
- [Integral numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)
- [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)
- [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0)
- [Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

Create a class named "Tirage".

**Tirage.cs**

```
namespace Lotto_649
{
    //on defini la classe tirage qui est utiliser pour lire le fichier CSV
    public class Tirage
    {
        public DateTime t_Date { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
        public int B1 { get; set; } = 0;
        public int B2 { get; set; } = 0;
        public int B3 { get; set; } = 0;
        public int B4 { get; set; } = 0;
        public int B5 { get; set; } = 0;
        public int B6 { get; set; } = 0;
        public int Comp { get; set; } = 0;
        public int Somme_Tir_wo_Compl { get; set; } = 0;
        public int Pair { get; set; } = 0;
        public string Montant { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Even_Odd { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Bucket { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public Tirage(DateTime t_Date, int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4, int b5, int b6, int comp, string montant, string even_odd, string bucket)
        {
            // Date,Boule 1,Boule 2,Boule 3,Boule 4,Boule 5,Boule 6,Complementaire,Valeur,Even - Odd,Buckets

            this.t_Date = t_Date;

            this.B1 = b1;
            this.B2 = b2;
            this.B3 = b3;
            this.B4 = b4;
            this.B5 = b5;
            this.B6 = b6;
            this.Comp = comp;
            this.Montant = montant;
            this.Even_Odd = even_odd;
            this.Bucket = bucket;

            this.Somme_Tir_wo_Compl = B1 + B2 + B3 + B4 + B5 + B6;

            // count the nombre de boule pair.

            if (B1 % 2 == 0)
                Pair++;
            if (B2 % 2 == 0)
                Pair++;
            if (B3 % 2 == 0)
                Pair++;
            if (B4 % 2 == 0)
                Pair++;
            if (B5 % 2 == 0)
                Pair++;
            if (B6 % 2 == 0)
                Pair++;

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string str = $"{t_Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} {B1} {B2} {B3} {B4} {B5} {B6} {Comp} {Montant} {Even_Odd} {Pair}";
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice the following in the code below:

```
do
{
    ...

} while (true);
```

which is an infinite loop. `break` is used to exit the loop, once the desired condition has been met.

For the code that is in "Program.cs", below I'll show two different options. It's two different solutions to achieve the same outcome.

Option 1, will use class variables which will allow multiple methods to have access to the data the variables contain.

**Option 1** - (Overview):

In the example below, notice that `MenuPrincipale` has a return type of `void`. Since `s_MenuLottoChoice`, is a class variable, it can be accessed by any method within the class.

```
class Program
{
    private static int s_MenuLottoChoice = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                    ...

        MenuPrincipale();

                    ...

        switch (s_MenuLottoChoice)
        {
                    ...
        }

                    ...
    }

    private static void MenuPrincipale()
    {
                    ...

        Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine($"Select the lotto type");
        Console.WriteLine($"1 - 649");
        Console.WriteLine($"2 - Lotto Max");
        Console.WriteLine($"Q - Quit Program");
        Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
        Console.Write($"Enter selection: ");

        string userSelection = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

        //try to convert to int
        bool parseSucceeded = Int32.TryParse(userSelection, out s_MenuLottoChoice);

                    ...
    }
}
```

**Option 1** - Program.cs (full code)

```
namespace Lotto_649
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string s_csvFilename = @"C:\Users\repos\CSV-Reader-with-lotto\Tirage649.csv";
        private static List<Tirage> s_tirages = new List<Tirage>();
        private static int s_MenuLottoChoice = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int nbBoule = 0;//49 for 649 and 50 for Lotto_MAX

            //load the draw based on the choice
            MenuPrincipale();

            switch (s_MenuLottoChoice)//faire une selection
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Loading 649");
                    Load649Csv();//call method for loading the 649 drwas
                    nbBoule = 49;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("To Do Lotto MAX");
                    //LoadLottoMax();//call method for the lotto max draw 
                    nbBoule = 50;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Error - Break");//any other keys
                    break;
            }//end switch

            //int dernierTirageACompter = s_tirages.Count;
            //Console.WriteLine($"dernier tirage: {dernierTirageACompter}");
            Console.WriteLine($"dernier tirage: {s_tirages.Count}");


            DisplayData(); //display data

        }

        //---------------------------Declaring the method used in the main program

        //Display data
        public static void DisplayData()
        {
            //output results
            if (s_tirages != null)
            {
                foreach (Tirage t in s_tirages)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: s_tirages is null");
            }
        }

        //Load the 649 draw in the array. 
        public static void Load649Csv()
        {
            //check if filename exists
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(s_csvFilename))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: File doesn't exist: '{s_csvFilename}'");
                return;
            }

            //read the content of the CSV file as plain text
            //read all the lines and put it directly into an array
            //Date,Boule 1,Boule 2,Boule 3,Boule 4,Boule 5,Boule 6,Complementaire,Valeur,Even - Odd,Buckets

            string[] csvAllTirage649 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(s_csvFilename);

            int numDrawToCheck = 0;//how many draws to check


            //since 1st line is header, need to subtract 1 
            Console.WriteLine($"There are {csvAllTirage649.Length - 1} entries in the file.");

            //prompt user for selection
            //if an invalid entry was made, re-prompt
            do
            {
                Console.Write($"How many results to load? ");

                //get user selection
                //remove any leading/trailing spaces and newline
                string userSelection = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

                //convert to int
                Int32.TryParse(userSelection, out numDrawToCheck);

                if (numDrawToCheck < 1 || numDrawToCheck > csvAllTirage649.Length - 1)
                {
                    //inform user of invalid selection
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nError: Invalid selection '{userSelection}'. Please try again.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    //user selection is valid. exit loop
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);
           
            if (csvAllTirage649 != null && csvAllTirage649.Length > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= numDrawToCheck; i++)//start with 1 since the first line is the content header
                {
                    string[] data = csvAllTirage649[i].Split(',');

                    //ToDo: ensure date format is correct
                    DateTime t_Date = DateTime.ParseExact(data[0].Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    int b1 = 0;
                    int b2 = 0;
                    int b3 = 0;
                    int b4 = 0;
                    int b5 = 0;
                    int b6 = 0;
                    int comp = 0;
                    string montant = string.Empty;
                    string even_odd = string.Empty;
                    string bucket = string.Empty;

                    Int32.TryParse(data[1], out b1); //try to convert to int
                    Int32.TryParse(data[2], out b2); //try to convert to int
                    Int32.TryParse(data[3], out b3); //try to convert to int
                    Int32.TryParse(data[4], out b4); //try to convert to int
                    Int32.TryParse(data[5], out b5); //try to convert to int
                    Int32.TryParse(data[6], out b6); //try to convert to int
                    Int32.TryParse(data[7], out comp); //try to convert to int

                    montant = data[8].Trim();
                    even_odd = data[9].Trim();
                    bucket = data[10].Trim();

                    //add to list
                    s_tirages.Add(new Tirage(t_Date, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, comp, montant, even_odd, bucket));
                }
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine($"{s_tirages.Count} results are loaded");
   
        }// End Load649Csv

        //----------------------Print to screen the menu---------------------------------
        private static void MenuPrincipale()
        {
            //prompt user for selection
            //if an invalid entry was made, re-prompt
            //allow the user to exit the program if desired
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine($"Select the lotto type");
                Console.WriteLine($"1 - 649");
                Console.WriteLine($"2 - Lotto Max");
                Console.WriteLine($"Q - Quit Program");
                Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
                Console.Write($"Enter selection: ");

                //get user selection
                //remove any leading/trailing spaces and newline
                string userSelection = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

                //try to convert to int
                bool parseSucceeded = Int32.TryParse(userSelection, out s_MenuLottoChoice);

                if (userSelection == "Q" || userSelection == "q")
                {
                    //exit the program
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else if (s_MenuLottoChoice < 1 || s_MenuLottoChoice > 2)
                {
                    //inform user of invalid selection
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nError: Invalid selection {userSelection}. Please try again.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    break; //exit loop
                }

            } while (true);
            //menu principale

            //end menuprincipale
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2, will pass data back to the calling method by returning it from the method that was called.

**Options 2** - (Overview):

In the example below, notice that `MenuPrincipale` has a return type of `int`. The method must return an `int` value. The value of `result` is made available by returning it from the method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                    ...

        int menuLottoChoice = MenuPrincipale();

                    ...

        switch (menuLottoChoice)
        {
                    ...
        }

                    ...
    }

    private static int MenuPrincipale()
    {
        int result = 0;

                    ...

        Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine($"Select the lotto type");
        Console.WriteLine($"1 - 649");
        Console.WriteLine($"2 - Lotto Max");
        Console.WriteLine($"Q - Quit Program");
        Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
        Console.Write($"Enter selection: ");

        string userSelection = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

        //try convert to int
        bool parseSucceeded = Int32.TryParse(userSelection, out result);

                    ...

        return result;   
    }
}
```

**Option 2** - Program.cs (full code)

```
namespace Lotto_649
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string s_csvFilename = @"C:\Users\repos\CSV-Reader-with-lotto\Tirage649.csv";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Tirage> tirages = new List<Tirage>();

            int nbBoule;//49 for 649 and 50 for Lotto_MAX

            //load the draw based on the choice
            int menuLottoChoice = MenuPrincipale();

            switch (menuLottoChoice)//faire une selection
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Loading 649");
                    tirages = Load649Csv();//call method for loading the 649 drwas
                    nbBoule = 49;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("To Do Lotto MAX");
                    //LoadLottoMax();//call method for the lotto max draw 
                    nbBoule = 50;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Error - Break");//any other keys
                    break;
            }//end switch

            //int dernierTirageACompter = tirages.Count;
            //Console.WriteLine($"dernier tirage: {dernierTirageACompter}");
            Console.WriteLine($"dernier tirage: {tirages.Count}");

            DisplayData(tirages); //display data

        }

        //---------------------------Declaring the method used in the main program

        //Display Dat
        public static void DisplayData(List<Tirage> tirages)
        {
            //output results
            if (tirages != null)
            {
                foreach (Tirage t in tirages)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: s_tirages is null");
            }
        }

        //Load the 649 draw in the array. 
        public static List<Tirage> Load649Csv()
        {
            var tirages = new List<Tirage>();

            //check if filename exists
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(s_csvFilename))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: File doesn't exist: '{s_csvFilename}'");
                return null;
            }

            //read the content of the CSV file as plain text
            //read all the lines and put it directly into an array
            //Date,Boule 1,Boule 2,Boule 3,Boule 4,Boule 5,Boule 6,Complementaire,Valeur,Even - Odd,Buckets
            string[] csvAllTirage649 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(s_csvFilename);

            int numDrawToCheck = 0;//how many draws to check


            //since 1st line is header, need to subtract 1 
            Console.WriteLine($"There are {csvAllTirage649.Length - 1} entries in the file.");

            //prompt user for selection
            //if an invalid entry was made, re-prompt
            do
            {
                Console.Write($"How many results to load? ");

                //get user selection
                //remove any leading/trailing spaces and newline
                string userSelection = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

                //try to convert to int
                bool parseSucceeded = Int32.TryParse(userSelection, out numDrawToCheck);

                if (numDrawToCheck < 1 || numDrawToCheck > csvAllTirage649.Length - 1)
                {
                    //inform user of invalid selection
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nError: Invalid selection '{userSelection}'. Please try again.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    //user selection is valid. exit loop
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);
           
            if (csvAllTirage649 != null && csvAllTirage649.Length > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= numDrawToCheck; i++)//start with 1 since 0 content the header
                {
                    string[] data = csvAllTirage649[i].Split(',');

                    //ToDo: ensure date format is correct
                    DateTime t_Date = DateTime.ParseExact(data[0].Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    int b1 = 0;
                    int b2 = 0;
                    int b3 = 0;
                    int b4 = 0;
                    int b5 = 0;
                    int b6 = 0;
                    int comp = 0;
                    string montant = string.Empty;
                    string even_odd = string.Empty;
                    string bucket = string.Empty;

                    Int32.TryParse(data[1], out b1);
                    Int32.TryParse(data[2], out b2);
                    Int32.TryParse(data[3], out b3);
                    Int32.TryParse(data[4], out b4);
                    Int32.TryParse(data[5], out b5);
                    Int32.TryParse(data[6], out b6);
                    Int32.TryParse(data[7], out comp);

                    montant = data[8].Trim();
                    even_odd = data[9].Trim();
                    bucket = data[10].Trim();

                    //add to list
                    tirages.Add(new Tirage(t_Date, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, comp, montant, even_odd, bucket));
                }
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine($"{tirages.Count} results are loaded");
   
            return tirages;
        }// End Load649Csv

        //----------------------Print to screen the menu---------------------------------
        private static int MenuPrincipale()
        {
           
            int result = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine($"Select the lotto type");
                Console.WriteLine($"1 - 649");
                Console.WriteLine($"2 - Lotto Max");
                Console.WriteLine($"Q - Quit Program");
                Console.WriteLine($"-------------------------------");
                Console.Write($"Enter selection: ");

                string userSelection = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

                //try convert to int
                bool parseSucceeded = Int32.TryParse(userSelection, out result);

                if (userSelection == "Q" || userSelection == "q")
                {
                    //exit the program
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else if (result < 1 || result > 2)
                {
                    //inform user of invalid selection
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nError: Invalid selection {userSelection}. Please try again.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    //user selection is valid. exit loop
                    break;
                }

            } while (true);
            //menu principale

            return result;
            
            //end menuprincipale
        }
    }
}
```

The following test data was used but may not be valid due to the fact that only a single line of test data was supplied. Assumptions were made in order to create additional test data.

**Tirage649.csv**

```
Date, Boule 1, Boule 2, Boule 3, Boule 4, Boule 5, Boule 6, Complementaire, Valeur, Even - Odd, Buckets
2021-06-04, 5, 10, 12, 25, 27, 32, 3, 111M, 2O, 32453
2021-06-02, 3, 15, 22, 24, 28, 34, 2, 126M, 5E, 32454
2021-05-30, 1, 11, 20, 23, 26, 30, 5, 111M, 3O, 32455
2021-05-25, 4, 12, 18,1 9, 21, 29, 15, 118M, 6E, 32456
2021-03-21, 3, 5, 12, 23, 35, 49, 23, 45M, 3E, 32452
```

Comment: @B4SE: I've updated the code above to work with the sample data you supplied.