# How do I prevent the same number from being entered twice in my lottery program in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I have an assignment due today and I am pretty much done. The assignment is to make a lottery with arrays which I have done, but the last step is to make it so that the user can't enter the same number twice. If that happens, the program should tell the user to enter a new number. Here is my code:

```cs
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the lottery!");

static int GetGuess()
{
    int guess = 0;
    bool ok = false;

    while(!ok)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor= ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.WriteLine("Type in a number between 1 and 25");
        Console.ResetColor();
        ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out guess);

        if(!ok)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor= ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            Console.WriteLine("Inaccurate input");
        }
    }

    return guess;
}

int[] myArray = new int[5];
int guess;

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    guess = GetGuess();

    if(guess > 0 && guess < 26)
    {
        myArray[i] = guess;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor= ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a number between 1 and 25");
        i--;
    }

}

foreach (int i in myArray)
    Console.Write(i + " ");

Random rnd = new Random();
int dragning = rnd.Next(1, 26);
int rightAnswerAmount = 0;

foreach(int i in myArray)
{
    if (i == dragning)
        rightAnswerAmount++;
}

Console.ForegroundColor= ConsoleColor.Green;

if (rightAnswerAmount> 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Congratz! You had {0} amount of wins!", rightAnswerAmount);
else
    Console.WriteLine("You lost all your money");
```

I tried to use "if" and "else" to make it work but it didn't

Comment: You can create an [mcve] using https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and share the link and then describe what it is that does not work. Instead of just stating "i tried an if" you should actually show the attempted code as well as include what your thought process was to solve the problem (what should the code do logically if you had to describe how it accomplishes the requirement).

Comment: And as a side note but important if you want people to help you: Please  format your code. codewithoutformattingisdifficulttoreadjustimagineifsomeonesuppliedananswerlikethiswithoutanytypeofformatting.

Comment: Im sorry i just dont know how to do these things, im very new

Comment: it seems you store the guesses inside `myArray` so there should be a loop that runs through the entire array checking each element if it is equal to the current guess.

Comment: if (myArray.Contains(guess)) Console.WriteLine("Number already used.");

Comment: beside your actual question and the formatting: you only ever generate one random number. Assuming you don't guess the same number twice, you can only get a single number correct.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68138904/10024425

Comment: You may also want to learn about [Nested statement blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements#nested-statement-blocks). Also see [Understanding Scope and Accessibility Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/csharp-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners/understanding-scope-and-accessibility-modifiers)

Answer (score 0):

A fairly easy way to check if a number has occurred before is to use a `HashSet`. Since this is a *Set* it does not store duplicate values. The [add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=net-8.0) returns true if the number was added, or false if it already exist in the set:

```
var previousGuesses = new HashSet<int>();
...
while(!previousGuesses.Add(GetGuess()){
   Console.WriteLine("You already made this guess, guess another number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having all the validations in one method - `Guesses` - which generate a enumeration of guesses:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Guesses(int from, int upTo, int count) { 
  var unique = new HashSet<int>();

  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    while (true) {
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
      Console.WriteLine($"Type in a number between {from} and {upTo}");

      if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int v)) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.WriteLine("Inaccurate input"); 
      }
      else if (v < from || v > upTo) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.WriteLine($"You didn't enter a number between {from} and {upTo}"); 
      } 
      else if (!unique.Add(v)) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.WriteLine($"You made this guess ({v}), guess another number");
      }
      else {
        yield return v;

        break;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

usage

```
int rightAnswerAmount = 0;

Random rnd = new Random();

int dragning = rnd.Next(1, 26);

// No validation, arrays, messages here: 
// we get 5 valid guesses from 1 up to 25
foreach (int guess in Guesses(1, 25, 5)) {
  if (guess == dragning) {
    rightAnswerAmount += 1;
  }
}
```

Or you can even get rid of loop and *query* with a help of Linq:

```
// Try not creating your own Random without seed, 
// use precreated Random.Shared instead
dragning = Random.Shared.Next(1, 26);

int rightAnswerAmount = Guesses(1, 25, 5).Count(guess => guess == dragning);
```